# Qual a diferença entre Reduce e Foldl em Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Me peguei precisando de uma função `reduce` (por ter mais costume com JS esse é o primeiro nome que vem na cabeça) no Elixir e encontrei a `Enum.reduce/2`, porém com um pouco mais de pesquisa já no módulo de listas encontrei o `List.foldl/2`, pelo que vi eles me parecem idênticos.

Existe alguma diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em termos de comportamento não existe diferença nenhuma entre o `Enum.reduce/3` e `List.foldl/3`. A existência do `Enum.reduce/3` é que, dado qualquer estrutura que tenha o **protocol** `Enumerable` implementado será possivel usar, não só o `Enum.reduce/3`, mas todas as funções do módulo `Enum`. Já o `List.foldl/3` só vai poder ser usado em listas (veja a guard de sua definição abaixo `is_list/1`, é obrigatório ser `true`).

Por de baixo dos panos o Elixir vai usar a função `foldl/3` do Erlang para realmente efetuar a operação de reduce nos dois módulos:

#### Definição do foldl para `List`

```
  @spec foldl([elem], acc, (elem, acc -> acc)) :: acc when elem: var, acc: var
  def foldl(list, acc, fun) when is_list(list) and is_function(fun) do
    :lists.foldl(fun, acc, list)
  end
```

#### Definição do reduce para o `Enum`

```
  @spec reduce(t, acc, (element, acc -> acc)) :: acc
  def reduce(enumerable, acc, fun) when is_list(enumerable) do
    :lists.foldl(fun, acc, enumerable)
  end

  def reduce(first..last//step, acc, fun) do
    reduce_range(first, last, step, acc, fun)
  end

  def reduce(%_{} = enumerable, acc, fun) do
    reduce_enumerable(enumerable, acc, fun)
  end

  def reduce(%{} = enumerable, acc, fun) do
    :maps.fold(fn k, v, acc -> fun.({k, v}, acc) end, acc, enumerable)
  end

  def reduce(enumerable, acc, fun) do
    reduce_enumerable(enumerable, acc, fun)
  end
```

Um exemplo desse comportamento na prática é o `Scrivener`, um paginador de consultas para Elixir. Segue o link da implementação dele para o protocolo `Enumerable`: https://github.com/drewolson/scrivener/blob/master/lib/scrivener/page.ex

Answer (score 2):

*Reduce* usa o primeiro elemento da sequência como ponto inicial no que fará. *Fold* tem um valor inicial passado para começar. Então se você for somar todos elementos de uma coleção e quiser que o valor inicial seja 0, ambos darão o mesmo resultado, mas se deseja que comece por uma valor diferente só é possível fazer com `foldl`. Claro, para este exemplo é possível somar esse valor inicial, mas há casos que o que está fazendo não funciona bem assim. Na maioria dos casos só quer percorrer os elementos e tratar com eles, então o `reduce` é mais comum. O tipo pode prover um ou outro, como pode observar nesses exemplos.

Comment: Hmm, na verdade não deve ser isso não, pois no `reduce`, eu também posso definir um valor inicial com a `reduce/3` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3 , mas foi erro meu, não existe `foldl/2` apenas `foldl/3`, acabei confundindo. Mas então a única diferença é o tipo? O `foldl` é pra listas e o `reduce` mais genérico por pertencer ao módulo `Enum`?

Comment: No caso específico até não existe uma em certas coleções de dados e a outra não existe em outras, mas o que diferente mesmo deveria ser isto que te falei.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com no caso específico? Existe alguma definição formal da palavra? Sobre os tipos dizia que o Enum trabalha com estruturas que utilizam o protocolo Enum ou Stream, enquanto as Listas, apenas o tipo List (não "enumerable") ... Até então, sua resposta deixou de ser útil

Comment: Mas e defifnição da diferença é essa, talvez você queria saber algo que não está na pergunta.

Comment: Qual definição? A minha pergunta foi simples e direta, existe diferença? Claro que seria legal ver qual é a diferença, mas o que você me mostrou não era uma, a discussão aqui abaixo que mostrou uma delas, e talvez seja a única. releia sua resposta e veja que ela não me responde, ou melhor, responde, mas não é correta (e nem tenho como remover o ponto). O único engano que tive na pergunta foi o arity de 2 no foldl que não existe, e talvez isso tenha gerado o problema na sua resposta.